# revert statement causes infinite gas estimation in Remix

Tags: remix, gas, gas-estimate, revert

I wrote an Ownable contract snippet that uses revert instead of require on the OnlyOwner modifier. This causes remix to estimate infinite gas fees.
Does anyone know why?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

contract Ownable
{

    address public Owner;

    event OnTransferOwnership(address PreviousOwner, address NewOwner);
    
    error NotOwner(address NotOwnerAddress, address OwnerAddress);
    
    function IsOwner(address InAddress) public view returns (bool)
    {
        return InAddress == Owner;
    }
    
// This causes infinite gas estimate on RenounceOwnership
    modifier OnlyOwner()
    {
        /*
        require(IsOwner(msg.sender));
        _;
        */
        if(!IsOwner(msg.sender))
        {
            revert NotOwner({
                NotOwnerAddress: msg.sender,
                OwnerAddress: Owner
            });
        }
        _;
    }

    function TransferOwnership(address NewOwner) public OnlyOwner
    {
        address PreviousOwner = Owner;
        Owner = NewOwner;
        emit OnTransferOwnership(PreviousOwner, Owner);
    }

    function RenounceOwnership() public OnlyOwner
    {
        Owner = 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000;
    }

    constructor()
    {
        Owner = msg.sender;
    }

}
```

Comment: Which network is your target? For some old networks revert opcode doesn't exists so it will map to invalid opcode that consumes all available gas.

Comment: @Ismael I am not targeting any network yet, this just shows up in the Remix IDE. I asked on the Discord and they said that it would be normal.